# Application event propagation

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can please someone explain how will the application event propagation take place when the components are not related to each other ?

Application markup :

```
<aura:application>
    <c:aeNotifier/> // fires the event 
    <c:aeHandler/> // handles the event
    <c:aeHandlerTwo/> // handles the event   
</aura:component>
```

Please can you explain how the event propagation would take place in the capture, bubble and default phases?

Answer (score 4):

First, `aura:application` and `c:aeNotifier` will be notified of the capture phase, in that order. Second, `c:aeNotifier` and `aura:application` will be notified of the bubble phase, in that order. Finally, both `c:aeHandler` and `c:aeHandlerTwo` will be notified of the default phase in some non-deterministic order. You can read more about this in [Application Event Propagation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_propagation.htm). This presumes that no handler calls `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.preventDefault()`.